# pm2 loop restarting with sailsjs

Tags: node.js, sails.js, pm2

I have a problem with pm2. 
My start json is

```
{
"apps" : [{
    "name"        : "sails",
    "script"      : "app.js",
    "log_date_format"  : "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm Z",
    "ignoreWatch" : ["[\\/\\\\]\\./", "node_modules", ".tmp", "views", "assets", ".idea"],
    "watch"       : true
}]
}
```

Then i do

`pm2 start dev.json`

PM2 goes to infinity restarting with this message

```
PM2: 2015-02-11 14:56:39: Change detected for app name: sails - restarting
PM2: 2015-02-11 14:56:39: Process with pid 5766 still not killed, retrying...
PM2: 2015-02-11 14:56:39: App closed with code: 0
PM2: 2015-02-11 14:56:39: App name:sails id:0 exited
PM2: 2015-02-11 14:56:40: Process with pid 5766 killed
PM2: 2015-02-11 14:56:40: Starting execution sequence in -fork mode- for app name:sails id:0
PM2: 2015-02-11 14:56:40: App name:sails id:0 online
```

But no files was changed. It seems to be PM2 restarting after sails log out debug messages. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any log file written in the same folder? Try to know which files are changing and add them to the `ignoreWatch` attribute

Comment: Note that Sails also creates a *www* folder when run in production... You may want to add it to the ignore list, too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm solved this issue by switching a PM2 version frpm 0.12.5 to 0.11

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. Install the newest version that was released 3 days ago, 0.12.7 and see if the information in issue 969 link helps you out.

https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/issues/969